# StoryBoard 2 navigation controller pointing same View

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, storyboard

Does anyone know why this does not work?

[image]

With this, just one tab bar load the view, the other make black screen.
I Have tried without Navigation Controller, and Tab bar is correct and the other doesn't show the tabBar item in running mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer for this problem if anyone is interested.

[image: Add two views that will launch the view we are interested]

Add two views that will launch the view we are interested.
Same file for this 2 views :

```
@interface PushToAgenceViewController : UIViewController
@end

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"pushName" sender: self];
}
```