# 2 tab bar controller, 2 nav bar controller linked to ONE view (storyboard)

Tags: ios, tabs, controller, navigation, storyboard

I've got a problem with my application UI.
I want to link 2 tab bar controller to one view, but I don't know how to represent it?

To give you the context of my application, I have a series of views controller that give some useful support information for my app. I want theses view to be displayed on both of my tab bar controller menu (one tab bar controller is displayed when the user is logged in, and the other when he's not)

I thought of putting a view controller between the tab bar controller and the navigation controller, which could trigger the view I'm looking to display 'twice', but for some reasons I couldnt get it to work. (I'm not sure if it's the best implementation, too)

Here's a screenshot of what my storyboard look like right now:
http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/5913/41321932.png

Comment: Note that using a tabBarController that is not the root view is frowned upon by Apple.  Is this an enterprise app?  If so, try making a navigation controller your root view controller, and embedding your first tabBarController in that.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know about that! Yes it is an enterprise app. So overall, I only need *one* navigation controller ? Is that correct? Thanks for the anwser!

And will this make my problem go away with my view used in 2 tab bar controller? Gonna test this ASAP and reply back!

Comment: If the tabBarController is the root, the way it functions won't allow it to cover itself completely (except modally).  If you want to replace it, the navController as the root would allow that functionality.

Comment: It's possible I misunderstood your question, though.

Comment: Ohhh I get what you're saying, yeah you misunderstood! I want the tabBarController to be visible anytime (as it is right now) I don't want anything to cover it up! In my picture, the '1st nav bar (which is a navigation controller) has a push segue to the ViewController right beside it. that particular viewController has another push segue coming from the bottom... Which is linked to another navigationController! Right now when I run the app, both segue aren't working (they're push a black screen instead of my viewController) ... I hope this is more clear! :s

Comment: You don't want the navigation controller to have a push segue to its root view. Eliminate that push segue, and connect it as root view controller.

Comment: I got it partially working right now! The first navigationController which is linked as root view controller is working, but the second navigation controller (which I also tried to link as root view) is displaying a black screen... How can I link theses two to the viewController as root?

Comment: Control-click on the nav controller, and drag to the view controller.  At the bottom of the small scrollview that appears, select "root view".  You should be able to do that with both of them to the same controller.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did... But only the last segue I created is being affected when I run the app... 1st navigationController let's say navA and 2nd let's say navB. I link navA to the view controller, then navB to the view controller (as you said in your last reply) then when I run the app, only navB will show the content. If I do navB first, then navA well the result will be navA displaying the content but navB will have a black screen... I'm seriously out of idea... I don't get why I cannot link them at the same time!

Comment: I just found out that this guy was trying to do exactly the same thing I'm trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684787/storyboard-2-navigation-controller-pointing-same-view

But his solution only work partially once again for me... the navigation system isn't working well since I can back to a blank page which reload the viewcontroller. With this I can get the content from either navigationcontroller, but it isn't working well since I can hit the back button and reload the page, which create an infinite loop!